# Skipping a specific page in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a View pager with list of Fragments on its adapter. This is the scenario that I want to achieve:

Suppose we have 4 Fragments:
Fragment1
Fragment2
Fragment3
Fragment4

When I am in Fragment4 swiping back must lead me to Fragment2.
This would be the workflow:

Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3 -> Fragment4

Fragment1 <- Fragment2 <- Fragment4

I want to skip fragment3 when swiping from Fragment4.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project [Android-WizardPager](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager) by Roman Nurik. He is using method `recalculateCutOffPage` in `MainActivity` to block pages in ViewPager and add/remove them dynamically. I think you can use it as a base and extend it functionality to be also "swipe-back" compatible with your "dynamic" ViewPager.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes the sample app is very useful. But I want to skip pages not by clicking something or triggering something. But upon swiping from Fragment4 the next fragment that comes out should be Fragment2

Comment: Ok, an idea: when you reach fragment's 4 `setUserVisibleHint` modify fragment 3 replacing it with fragment 2 and since fragment 2 is 2 pages away be sure it will not be provided again with getItem from adapter. It needs some work to make it possible to work more then one time there-and-back (if you reach again fragment 1 you must do another tricks)

Comment: Thanks sir, ill give it a try. I'll let you know if I succeeded.